# Windows shortcuts not appearing after installation

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing an installer for my application and some start menu shortcuts are created during the installation. However, unless I install as administrator (which isn't required) some of the shortcuts fail to appear in the start menu after installation despite all of them being written. Here's the code I've written for reference:

```
IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell shell = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell();

IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut help_shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(shortcut_path + "\\KShootMania Skin Manager\\Help.lnk");
        help_shortcut.TargetPath = startup_shortcut.TargetPath;
        help_shortcut.Arguments = "help";
        help_shortcut.Save();

        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut uninstall_shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(shortcut_path + "\\KShootMania Skin Manager\\Uninstall.lnk");
        uninstall_shortcut.TargetPath = startup_shortcut.TargetPath;
        uninstall_shortcut.Arguments = "uninstall";
        uninstall_shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: If the instaler does not do all work properly, you do need adminsitrator rights. Installers and Updaters are the two kinds of programms that always need Adminsitrator rights. There is just too many places it might butt heads with the NTFS Right System to not have those rights. And adding a Manifest that forces Elevation should be easy enough.

Comment: Installers require admin rights. UAC prevents writing to most locations without elevation, and most corporate networks do not allow non-administrative users to install software. Stop trying to fight with the OS and do your installation properly, and you won't run into this sort of issue.

Comment: @KenWhite The installer doesn't write to any admin protected directories (it can and that works fine, but I want a user specific, non-admin installation option as well). It's writing to the start menu folder in the user's appdata directory, which isn't admin protected, hence the shortcuts are created without any issue, but the start menu only shows all of them if it was run as admin (despite them all being made regardless without such permissions).

Comment: *the start menu only shows all of them if it was run as admin* should make it clear that admin rights are required.

Comment: But to my understanding of how the start menu work, it just displays a list of all the shortcuts in the start menu folder it can find. It adds all the shortcuts fine, so I don't really see what's causing an issue. I feel like there's something I'm missing beyond it just working for some reason when running as an admin, because it just doesn't make sense to me for it to just magically work when being run as an admin. Sorry if this is just going around in circles.

Comment: Okay, I did a little more testing and it seems like it's only one specific shortcut that doesn't appear: The uninstall shortcut. I could see that only showing up if put there by an admin, but it's annoying.